# How to load a video from its string representation in OpenCV using Python?

Tags: python, rest, opencv

I'm writing a Rest-API function which should take a video from a post request, process the video using OpenCV and return a text response. I got stuck at reading the video from its string representation.

I looked at documentations that describe how to read a video in OpenCV and all of them are either reading from a path or from the webcam. For example, cv2.VideoCapture or FileVideoStream from imutils are all using the file path to load the video. However, I want to avoid redundant IO operations and don't want to write the video to a file first.

Related part in my project:

```py
    @app.route('/processvideo', methods = ['POST'])
        def process_video():
        # read as string
        fStr = request.files['file'].read() # file is read as string from the request

        npimg = np.fromstring(fStr, np.uint8) # string data is converted to numpy array.

        # image = cv2.imdecode(npimg, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) # this functions doesn't work, because it only takes image, not video.

        return jsonify( { 'output': 'test' } )
```

I'm sending the request in cli for test as follows:

```sh
    curl -F 'file=@demo.mp4' http://localhost:5000/processvideo
```

I want to process the incoming video frame by frame, so I need the frames as an image. Thanks from now for any help.

Comment: Hi @ErenL, did you find a solution?